# Setting.Secure ANDROID_ID is return different Value when using different APK

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I use this code:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

First I Install APK debug from my computer,

Then I Install APK from Play Store ANDROID_ID return different value

```
Install APK Debug: a4af9001bcf07f04
Install APK Play Store: 07ef710fb2c3a399
```

How do I fix this problem? Because it never happened before and I need it to check the API whether the user login from the same device or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is but obvious:

Have you checked documentation of [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID):

> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a
> 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each
> combination of app-signing key, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID
> are scoped by signing key and user. The value may change if a factory
> reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.
>
> **Note: For apps that were installed prior to updating the device to a version of Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, the value of
> ANDROID_ID changes if the app is uninstalled and then reinstalled
> after the OTA. To preserve values across uninstalls after an OTA to
> Android 8.0 or higher, developers can use Key/Value Backup.**

Answer (score 1):

That is because `unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID.

in your case debug and playstore probably has different signing keys which is why different identifiers.